# What is the range of $g(x)=\cos^{2n+1}(x)+\sin^{2n+1}(x)?$

Tags: trigonometry

We have that the range of $f(x)=\cos^{2n}(x)+\sin^{2n}(x),\; n\in \mathbb{N},\; n\geq 2,\;x\in \mathbb{R}$ is

$$f(x)\in[2^{1-n},1]$$

since with $t=\cos^2(x)$ such that $0\le t\le 1$, then

$$t^n+(1-t)^n.$$

The stationary points are the roots of

$$t^{n-1}-(1-t)^{n-1}=0$$ or $$t=\frac12.$$

What about the range of $g(x)=\cos^{2n+1}(x)+\sin^{2n+1}(x)?$

I have to find $b$ that $(b+1) f(x)-b g(x)=1$

Comment: What does $b$ have to do with the title of the question?

Answer (score 2):

Set $g(x)=\cos^{2n+1}{x}+\sin^{2n+1}{x}$  Then $$g'(x)=0\iff \cos^{2n}{x}\sin{x}=\sin^{2n}x\cos{x}\tag{1}$$  Clearly, the range of $g$ contains the interval $[-1,1]$ and we seek values outside this interval.  In analyzing $(1)$ therefore, we may assume $\sin{x}\neq0,\, \cos{x}\neq0.$ Then $(1)$ becomes $$\sin^{2n-1}{x}=\cos^{2n-1}{x}$$ so that we must consider the points $x$ such that $$\sin{x}=\cos{x}=\pm{1\over\sqrt{2}}$$  For such $x$, $$|g(x)|=2\cdot\left(2^{-1/2}\right)^{2n+1}=2^{(1-2n)/2}$$  If $n>0$ this value is less than $1$, but when $n=0$ it is greater than $1$.  $$\operatorname{Rng}(g)=\cases{\left[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}\right],&$n=0$\\ [-1,1],&$n>0$}$$

Comment: something about my last question?

Comment: @George Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: find $b$ that $(b+1) f(x)-b g(x)=1$

Comment: $b={1-f(x)\over f(x)-g(x)}$.  I don't see what this has to do with the problem, though.

Comment: Could we find all positive integers $n$ for which there is a real constant $b$ such that the above relation holds for every $x?$

Comment: @George There aren't any.  The right-hand side would have to be constant, and it isn't.  Just evaluate it at a couple of different values of $x$.